# e.nodeName is undefined Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I've racked my brains and went through it, looking at examples and don't understand why firebug is throwing "e.nodeName is undefined" error..

It's probably something stupid little bracket out of place or something that needs a second pair of eyes to see..
I'm just making a simple little ajax post for some inputs, but this is my first post ever, and I'm about close to pulling some hair off my head due to how many errors i've run into so far..
http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyDoe/aQYra/
*My script*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.hexen').after('<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" onClick="save();" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" onclick="save()"></div><br />') // ui icon
    .keypress(function () {
        $(this).next('.saveButton').show(); //appends ui icon
    });

        $('.saveButton').hide().click(function () {
            $(this).hide(); // removes ui icon on click
        });

        $('.ui-state-default').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    } //ui icon hover
    );
    });

    function save(value) {
        $('.hexen').each(function () {
            var id = null;
        });
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            id = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx",
        data: "{Id: " + $(".hexen").attr('id') + ", Value: " + $(".hexen").val() + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

*My HTML*

```
<div id="unvolitive">
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="Text1"/>
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="Text2"/>
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="Text3"/>
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="Text4"/>
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="Text5"/>
</div>
```

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Where in your code are you getting the error? On load, on the AJAX call, on event handlers, etc? It's generally best to only show the code involved in the error (and if you can figure that out in order to ask the question, you're often halfway to the answer yourself).

Comment: Firebug says its on "line 16".. Which is
`$(this).hide(); // removes ui icon on click`
I don't see anything wrong with this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think, from a brief fiddle test, that the issue comes from mixing normal jQuery event handlers and the `onclick` handler you're defining in the tag string (your `save` function).

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in `save`; the `each` call does nothing:

```
$('.hexen').each(function () {
    var id = null; // all this does is set a local variable
});
```

but more importantly, the way you've set this up with `onclick`, `this` will be undefined, so the following line won't work:

```
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
```

In this context, `this` refers to the `window` object, so I think that's why you're getting the error. To fix it, you should handle the save function in the jQuery-assigned click handler:

```
$('.saveButton').hide()
    .click(function () {
        $(this).hide(); // removes ui icon on click
        var id;
        // get the associated input
        var $input = $(this).prev('.hexen');
        if ($input.val() !== '') {
            id = $input.attr('id');
        }
        console.log(id);
        // presumably, do something with id now...
});
```

See a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/C8mrf/).

Answer (score 8):

The error happens in `save()` which uses `this` outside of context.. (*it refers to window currently*)

It should probably be

```
function save(value) {
    $('.hexen').each(function() {
        var id = null;
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            id = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    });
}
```

---

I *moved* the `if` part inside the `each` handler..

Comment: Hmm - good call, I think you guessed the OP's obscure intent here better than I did.

Comment: @nrabinowitz, Not sure though about the indent, because the original code has many parts that do nothing, or at least not what i believe the OP expects.. Such as using `$('.hexen').val()` which returns just the first occurrence etc..

Answer (score 1):

You defined in ajax call `dataType: json`, so your ajax call expects valid json returning from your server. It seems that you do not return valid json. I recommend deleting this line (`contentType` as well). If this is not the case, then I do not know what is. :)

By the way, you can define data like this:

```
data: {
  Id: $(".hexen").attr('id'),
  Value: $(".hexen").val()
}
```

No need to stringify it on your own.

Comment: Good suggestion.. But it's still throwing the e-nodename error

Comment: How about `ajax` call used outside `$(document).ready(...)`? This surely is a mistake.

Comment: One more thing: you should remove those `onclick(...)` from your `after` function. First of all there are two of them and what is more important you still override it in `$('.saveButton').hide().click(function () {...});`. Throws strange erros under Chrome.

Comment: @freakish - actually, `$(document).ready(...)` just insures that the DOM is ready for manipulation - if the AJAX call doesn't alter the DOM in the callback, there's no reason to wait for the `ready` event to call it.

Comment: @nrabinowitz But you try to read data into your ajax call from DOM.

Comment: @freakish - ah, you're right in this case. But generally speaking, you *can* use `$.ajax()` outside of `$(document).ready(...)` if there's no DOM stuff involved.

Comment: @nrabinowitz You're right, but doing ajax call at the very begining is a bit pointless, don't you think? You can just simply load the data when you load the page! Generally this is not a mistake (although in this context it is), but this is a bad practice, imho.

Comment: @freakish - what if you're loading dynamic data into a static page? Or loading data with JSONP from a service you don't control? There are good reasons to do this, though I don't think the OP's use-case is one of them.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Well, you never load data from exterior service before your DOM is loaded now do you? This is the context we're talking about. At least I didn't see that. But I might be wrong. :) I'm going to bed now - good night all! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a working link to tell where it's getting bogged down but I can tell you that the JSON you're posting is invalid.

```
"{Id: " + $(".hexen").attr('id') + ", Value: " + $(".hexen").val() + "}"
```

should be

```
"{'Id': '" + $(".hexen").attr('id') + "', 'Value': '" + $(".hexen").val() + "'}"
```